# Unbalanced Flink Streaming Load

Tags: apache-flink

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRCMm.jpg

I have a 4 nodes standalone Flink cluster. There is a TaskManager on every node (TM A, TM B, TM C, TM D) and every TaskManager has 2 slots (A1, A2, B1, ..., D2).

The source of the job runs with parallelism 8.
There are 6 map/flatMap from the source (all of them with par 2).

While checking the flow realised that all of the flatMap operations are using slot form the same TM (that's OK), but the overall job using only 2 of the TMs. So the load is very unbalanced.

Why is this behaviour? How can I balance the load?

Answer (score 1):

There are several relevant factors:

1. By default, whenever one operator forwards directly to the next, those operators are chained together to avoid serialization and networking overhead.
2. By default, the number of slots equals the maximum parallelism, and each slot is assigned to execute one complete slice of the application (one instance of each operator). If you want more control over the assignment of tasks to slots, you can set up slot sharing groups to isolate particular operators or groups of operators into their own slot(s).
3. The Flink scheduler assigns tasks to task slots without giving any thought to locality -- it only thinks in terms of slots, not task managers. There's been some discussion about doing a better job of spreading out the load across the available machines for cases like yours -- see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11815 -- and about providing more explicit control -- see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-11166.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `par 2` means parallelism 2.

So you job has parallelism 8 as default, but you are changing this default parallelism for your flatMap operators. So every flatMap operator will use 2 slots from 8 available.

The question is why your operators are not deployed to different slots instead using the same ones. Probably the key is that you have enabled operator chaining, where an operator will use the same thread in the same slot to optimise them.
So probably flatMap 1 is chained with flatMap 5, and flatMap 2 is chained with 3, 4 and 6 according to your picture.

Try to disable operator chaining and redeploy the application, probably your operators will be deployed in more TaskManagers.
If you want a fine grained control about chaining you can do it manually, or maybe you could consider to remove the per operator parallelism and just leave the default job parallelism.

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/concepts/runtime.html#tasks-and-operator-chains

Comment: thanks to the hint. 
I tried startNewChain() [ [source.flatmap.startNewChain.window.aggregation...](https://imgur.com/Sc3huMl) ] yet but that didn't work maybe because all of the flatmaps goes into the same sink. I got the same unbalanced load...


i'm going to try disableChaining()

Comment: tried with disableChaining() too.

with 12 TaskManagers and 2 slots on each. all the flatmaps, windows, aggregations run with parallelism 1.

and still all of the taskes with parallelism 1 run on the same Taskmanager. it seems disableChaining() has no effect :(